# How to show Google ads on parked domain and use that for emails too?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, nameserver, domain-parking

I have a parked domain where I would like to show Google ads, but Google wants that I put the domain on their name servers. I guess then they will point the domain to one of their IP.

My problem is that I want to use this domain for receiving mails too. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the A record in DNS to the IP given by Google. This will serve the ads to the visitor.

Then you set the MX record to your mail server. This will give you the possibility to receive mails.